# How it could be the table strucutre in mysql that allows have categories, subcategories and subcategories that are part from other subcategories?

Tags: mysql

Im gonna do a web app (php mysql) that allows manage passwords and other functions. One topic of this web app will be the categories, subcategories, subsubcategories, subsubsub...
Im stuck.

Answer (score 0):

recursive table ?

tb_categ(id_categ, descr_categ ,...., id_categ_father)

where id_categ_father is nullable and has as foreign key tb_categ.id_categ itself